# How to substitute the value obtained by JS into a specific place in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Both CSS and JS are reading with external files.

---

### What I want to do:

```
.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
margin-right: ?px;
background: transparent;
}
.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
margin-left: ?px;
background: transparent;
}
```

I would like to include the value obtained by subtracting 302px at this `?`.
In the formula, `? = (Window size) - 302px / 2` (`?` is the same value)

[image: like this]

---

### What I tried (latest edition) (didn't work):

```
$(function() {
   var typscrollWidth = $('.typ::after').width();   // get 302px
   var windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
   var typthumbCenter = windowWidth - typscrollWidth / 2;   //the above formula

   $('.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end').css('margin-right', 
     typthumbCenter + 'px');
   $('.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start').css('margin-left', 
     typthumbCenter + 'px');
});
```

I found an example that seems it can custom, so this is jQuery..
But I want to write in JavaScript.
(I'm sorry Andy, I still don't understand how to do it with variables in my example.. :'( )

Why not CSS? Because the effect I'm trying to do can't be done with CSS's automatic setting (e.g. `margin: auto;`)..

I don't understand JS so much :(
In this case, how should I write?
Someone, please help me!

---

### Add

As load every time, it shifts a bit like this. Once it change the window width it will be correct.
do you know why?

[image: like this]

---

### Code

The corresponding code is in the middle.
The code snippet looks correct when it is Full page. (Because it's manual adjustment now, only for environment with window width 1280px)

```css
html {font-size: 62.5%;}
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; box-sizing: border-box; list-style-type: none;}    /* reset */

.typ {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .typ::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 30.2rem;    /* Place of 302px */
  height: 1.6rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228080150.png");
 }

.typ-wrap {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8.3rem;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  writing-mode: bt-lr;
  /* IE */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
 }
.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: block;
  width: 33.2rem;
 }
.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
 }
 
 /*  from here  */ 
.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
  margin-right: 489px;    /* It's centered in Fullpage (In my environment) */
  background: transparent;
 }
.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
  margin-left: 489px;    /* It's centered in Fullpage (In my environment lol) */
  background: transparent;
 }
 /*  to here  */

.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
.typ-wrap ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 31.9rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
.typ-wrap li {
  display: inline-block;
 }
.typ-wrap li:first-child {
  margin-left: 3rem;
 }
.typ-wrap li:last-child {
  margin-right: 3rem;
 }
.typ-wrap li + li {
  margin-left: 3rem;
 }
```

```html
<div class="typ">
  <div class="typ-wrap">
   <ul>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075715.png" alt="あ=a" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075712.png" alt="い=b" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075710.png" alt="う=c" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075706.png" alt="え=d" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075704.png" alt="お=e" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075810.png" alt="か=f" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075807.png" alt="き=g" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075805.png" alt="く=h" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075802.png" alt="け=i" /></a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075759.png" alt="こ=j" /></a>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the full `HTML`, it's difficult to help as much as I'd like to. The basic idea is to use [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and update the variable from our `JavaScript` listeners.

Here's an example that updates the width of the element `.typ-wrap` to half of the viewport size.

```js
// Check on load
checkWindowWidth();

// Check on resize
$(window).on('resize', handleResize);

function handleResize() {
  checkWindowWidth();
}

function checkWindowWidth() {
  $(":root")[0].style.setProperty('--window-width', $(window).width());
  $('.typ-wrap').attr('data-window-width', $(window).width());
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  --window-width: 0;
}

.typ-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(var(--window-width) / 2 * 1px);
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.typ-wrap::after {
  content: attr(data-window-width) 'px';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.5em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="typ-wrap" data-window-width=""></div>
```

### Update (A solution!)

Looking at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) for the custom scrollbar, I did not see any mention of `:end` and `:start` as a suffix to `::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece`, which led me to think, *why not set both the margins on that instead?* So that's what I did.

`CSS` I added:

```css
.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  margin-left: calc(((var(--window-width) * 1px) - 302px) / 2);
  margin-right: calc(((var(--window-width) * 1px) - 302px) / 2);
  …
}
```

In our `JavaScript` we set the window width on both page load and the resize event.

```
$(":root")[0].style.setProperty('--window-width', $(window).innerWidth());
```

**Demo** (Chrome only):

```js
// Check on load
checkWindowWidth();

// Check on resize
$(window).on('resize', handleResize);

function handleResize() {
  checkWindowWidth();
}

function checkWindowWidth() {
  $(":root")[0].style.setProperty('--window-width', $(window).innerWidth());
}
```

```css
:root {
  --window-width: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* reset */

.typ {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.typ::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 30.2rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url("https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228080150.png");
}

.typ-wrap {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8.3rem;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  writing-mode: bt-lr;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: block;
  width: 33.2rem;
}

.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  margin-left: calc(((var(--window-width) * 1px) - 302px) / 2);
  margin-right: calc(((var(--window-width) * 1px) - 302px) / 2);
  background: transparent;
}

.typ-wrap::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.typ-wrap ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 31.9rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.typ-wrap li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.typ-wrap li:first-child {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

.typ-wrap li:last-child {
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.typ-wrap li+li {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="typ">
  <div class="typ-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075715.png"
                 alt="あ=a" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075712.png"
                 alt="い=b" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075710.png"
                 alt="う=c" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075706.png"
                 alt="え=d" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075704.png"
                 alt="お=e" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075810.png"
                 alt="か=f" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075807.png"
                 alt="き=g" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075805.png"
                 alt="く=h" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075802.png"
                 alt="け=i" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/O/O2_milk/20190228/20190228075759.png"
                 alt="こ=j" /></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

### Update II (Some explanation)

So, what the heck is this line anyway?

```css
margin-left: calc(((var(--window-width) * 1px) - 302px) / 2);
```

It's `CSS`, but pretty nested and complex looking. It's not too bad, though. Let's break it down.

```css
calc()
```

Think of it as a smart calculator for the web. It's built into `CSS` itself, and can do some clever things for us like add `41em + 50px`. Most people can't compute that off the of their head, but it's no problem for `calc()`. Just like a real calculator, you can perform multiple operations at once.

The only caveat is that a space must exist on either side of your operators (+,-,*,/).

**Good**

```css
calc(40% + 5px);
```

**Bad**

```css
calc(40%+5px);
```

Next we've got this part of the expression:

```css
((var(--window-width) * 1px)
```

Let's go inside out. The following is a number we're generating via `JavaScript`, both on first load and after resize happens.

```css
var(--window-width)
```

The thing is, though, the number has no units at the end of it. It might be `511`, but not `511px`. This leads us to the next part of that long equation, where we multiply the unit-less width `* 1px`. Remember when I said that `calc()` can take totally different units and join them into a single value? Well, by multiplying by `1px`, I'm forcing that width to be a `px` width.

Now that we've got the window width in `px` format, we subtract `302px` from it, the constant from your equation. Finally, we take the result from *all of that* and divide it by 2, accounting for the half the width of the scrollbar itself. We now have a dynamically centered scrollbar, ready for action.

Okay, take a breath. To answer your last question, I believe the small shift you're sometimes seeing comes down to sub-pixel rendering abnormalities that can occur in the browser at a given screen width. I see the shift sometimes, but not all the times. It probably depends on when the resize event fired and  how precise those final calculations are. I would chalk this up to hard to solve challenges that happen in dynamic element positioning like this, that sometimes re-fires every second. I'm not sure I can resolve this last part without a lot more investigation and work.

I hope through this whole question that you learned a few things. Maybe you can help someone down the road. Questions like these make it fun to participate on this site. Nice meeting you, POP!

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7r35hyg/)

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Thank you :D
Oh, that's right!
I updated the current status with code snippet.

Comment: I'm actually pretty sick. 101 fever. Give it a try yourself, though. I believe in you!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Thank you for everything!

Comment: @POP Thanks for being patient. This one took some time.

Comment: Wooow! Touching! Really thank you so much!! x)))
I was trying to manage it somehow from that, but it seemed to me that JS was too difficult and my head is going to explode..
I should write it like this That was a really big help. I'm very happy to move properly.
Thank you very much politely.

Comment: @POP It was challenging, which is good for me. If you're happy with things, all I ask is that you select my answer.

Comment: There are two questions. 1) What does `* 1px` of `calc(((var(--window-width) * 1px) - 302px) / 2)` mean?
 2) At the time of the loading, it shifts slightly each time (reference Add), but do you know why? (It will be normal if changing window width once)

Comment: @POP I will take a look in a little while when I return to my machine and will add an explanation for you.

Comment: @POP All right. Updated the answer to hopefully answer your questions. Take care.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really easy to understand.

Of course! Thanks to it I learned very much and thought that JavaScript was fun!
I'm really thankful to you. Nice meeting to you too, Andy :)

Comment: The last shift problem has also been solved!
[ $(window).width () → window.innerWidth ]
It seems that it was caused by customizing the vertical scroll bar of the browser to "don't display always".

Comment: @POP Ah, my `jQuery` is rusty. Excellent find. I will adjust the answer so the next person can benefit from your hard work. Nice design, by the way.

Comment: No, your work was perfect. I succeeded if I didn't customize the display state of the scroll bar. (confirmed)
Whoa! I'm so happy. Although it is still incomplete.. Thank you! x)